# errno 9 bad file descriptior in list python

Tags: python, image, list, url

i want to display a url with a image file (counter number like: `1.jpg`, `2.jpg`) and so on ... But i get on image number 72 errno 9 bad file descriptor, there are 126 pictures. here is my code:

```
# Iterate for each result and get unescaped url
for myUrl in dataInfo[:1]:
    count = count + 1
    #print myUrl['unescapedUrl']

    myopener.retrieve(myUrl['unescapedUrl'],str(count)+'.jpg')
    eurl.append('http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/products/'+str(count)+'.jpg')

    # Sleep for one second to prevent IP blocking from Google
    time.sleep(1)

csva.ausgabeNamenClose

for urlpc in eurl:
    print urlpc ### Here is the point of errno 9
```

Comment: Sure all the images exist and have a name as you expect it to be? No whitespaces or additional stuff on it? Is the extension as you expect it to be?

Comment: i test it aggain there are only 99 images there the errorn 9 is maybe from there ...

Comment: Try closing what myopener opens on each iteration.

Comment: how cant find how to close